# Check if it's the window object

Tags: javascript

Given that my plugin could be run on any JS engine (in a browser or not),

- How does one know that some variable is actually the browser `window` object.

  Like how do I know if `someVar` references the browser `window` object. Is there something in `window` that I can check if it is really the browser `window` object?
- And how to check if the browser `window` object actually exists and not just some `window` variable containing an object.

  Suppose you can't tell if `someVar` is `window` by itself, and you want to match it against the *real* browser `window` object like `someVar === window`, how do you get `window` that you are sure it is the browser `window` and not some other object from an outer scope named `window`, or some other global from another environment?

Just to clarify a bit more:

- I'm not looking for the global of the environment. I'm looking for the browser `window` object specifically.
- I'm not checking if the script is running on the browser.

I can't do something like `if(!window)` since `window` could just be another object declared somewhere outside the scope.

```
function someFunction(){
  var window = {foo:'bar'};

  (function(){
    console.log(window); //{foo:'bar'}
  }());
}
```

I can't check `if(window.window === window)` since I can also do self referencing, and like said earlier, `window` could be an object from an outer scope:

```
var bar = {};
bar.bar = bar;
bar.bar.bar.bar.bar.bar === bar; //true
```

And the following may not work since the script could be wrapped or concatenated within something other than the global space. `this` could also be modified with calls like `call()`, `apply()` or `bind()`.

```
//Stand-alone, I can assume window is global since "this" is the global in global space
(function(window){
  //window may not be window
}(this));

//But when this happens
someNamespace.someFunction = function(){

  (function(window){
    //window may not be window
  }(this));

}

//or this:
someNamespace.someFunction.call({});
```

I have a feeling that this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find where I first saw it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check whether a script is running under node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224606/how-to-check-whether-a-script-is-running-under-node-js)

Comment: It sounds like you want to determine whether your code is running in a browser or not by checking if window exists. You could try looking for features that a browser might implement as part of window such as window.location.href, but of course even this is not fail safe. How about determining if you can return a valid userAgent string?

Comment: Would `(function(){return this}).call(null)` always work?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Nope.  In ES3 environments it would, but ES5 changed the rules to say that the `thisArg` is not changed to the global object when `null` is explicitly passed.  For instance, this will return null: `(function () { "use strict"; return (function(){return this}).call(null); })()`.

Comment: @AndyE when is it changed to `thisArg`, then? Can a similar approach be used?

Comment: @JanDvorak: the only way to get the global object from anywhere in strict mode is to use the approach in alex's answer or a "variant" eval approach like `Function('return this')()`.

Comment: @AndyRay That answer accepts both `global` and `window` as `root`. How do you know if the global object is the browser `window` object?

Comment: @series0ne Nope, I'm not checking if the script is running in the browser, I'm checking if `window` is the browser `window` object and not some other object named `window`.

Answer (score 4):

This will not only test for current window, but for window in general:

```
    if (window.toString() === "[object Window]") {
         // your code here
    }
```

---

[edit]

`toString()` object prototype was available from JavaScript initial version 1.0 and was an old fashioned way to check for the "class". As well as the method mentioned in another answer to this question - to check for the unique object propert, which is faster to execute than string comparison.

Since JavaScript 1.4 (ECMAScript 3rd edition 1999) we are able to utilize `instanceof` operator to check for the object Class which is the right method for this task.

```
    if (window instanceof Window) {
         // your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the global object like so...

```
var global = (1,eval)("this");
```

Comment: Is it possible without `eval` (or `new Function`)?

Comment: @JanDvorak: I'm pretty sure it's not.

Comment: I can't get part with `1` char. We actualy run `eval` on `"this"` string. How `1` involved here?

Comment: @tommi it's just a method of making an indirect call to *eval()*. The 1 isn't relevant (it could be any valid expression), what matters is that you don't call *eval()* directly. This is how you can evaluate code in the global scope from anywhere. It doesn't work in IE8 and lower though.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
function isWindow() {
    _test = 42;
    return window && window._test == 42
}
```

Comment: except you should test if `_test` is not already present in `window`, and if it is, test with some other value.

Comment: Also, don't forget to roll back your test after you're done with it ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak: yes, but if there's NO window - how do I roll back?

Comment: This is also susceptible to `var window = this`, which I think the OP is (perhaps a little too) worried about.

Answer (score 1):

I found it while understanding creating instances through

```
var MyExampleInstace = function MyExampleInstace() {
    console.log(this); // returns undefined in strict mode
    // in not strict mode it will return Window 
}

new MyExampleInstace(); // will not return and error (this will be fine)
```

I wanted to create an error like

```
throw new Error('Please use "new" keyword');
```

When somebody tries to call MyExampleInstance not as instance but as simple function like:

```
MyExampleInstance(); // console should show "Please use "new" keyword
```

So the final result was:

```
var MyExampleInstace = function MyExampleInstace() {
    if (this === undefined || this instanceof Window) throw new Error('Please use "new" keyword');
}
```

To check the object is the object of some "kind" the most simple way I found through

```
// myVar could be "this" or every var u need
// That's also opens the way to check the object instance of your MyExampleInstance
myVar instanceof Window
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Answer (score 0):

You can check it if you use some methods supported just by the object window.
For example postMessage:

```
(function(o){ 
 if(!!o.postMessage) console.log("This is my window"); 
 else console.log("This isn't my window");
})(window);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if( this.window === this )
```

Comment: "the script could be wrapped in something other than the global space"

Comment: then save a reference to `this` at the top of the file. jesus.

Comment: "the script" refers to the entire file, I assume. No need to be rude.

Comment: In which case I'm afraid the asker's script is not a file. Or maybe it is a file that is included somewhere. Or maybe it's an environment where "all files execute in the global context" doesn't hold. Or maybe it's an environment where the concept of a file doesn't exist. There is a lot of environments, and you can't just assume the asker will be able to place anything anywhere but in the script itself, and "the script could be wrapped in something other than the global space".

Comment: Our manager at a company I formerly worked really likes configurable things, and he wanted things to be done as fast as possible. Of course, coding for a database access is faster than coding for a file access. Well, it turns out that javascript is not always stored in a file, and it is by far not always injected to the global scope. Sure, there are reasons to not do that, but PHP injection and Javascript injection by the administrators are better than having to code one hour longer. And, sometimes these scriptlets end up being _not_ inside the global scope, but, say, a jQuery `click` handler.