# How to detect if script is running in browser or in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have jasmine test spec file and I want to run it using both node.js and in browser. How can I detect if script is running in node?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575790/environment-detection-node-js-or-browser

Comment: use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-is-node

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功 it was asked 5 years ago but I think this is better answer, the solution looks beter.

Comment: Hi there, date does not matter much BTW, I just go by question upvotes since it is so hard to decide answer quality. Answers can be migrated if not covered on the other question.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

You can check for the window global object, if it is available then you are in a browser

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined')
// this is node
```

Or you can check for the process object, if it is available then you are in node

```
if(typeof process === 'object')
// this is also node
```

Comment: I found that many proposed solutions stop working if the code has been webpack'd, because webpack defines all kinds of `process`, `module`, `require`, etc symbols. `window` usually still works, unless of course you additionally also want to detect being run from a webworker, where there is no `window`.

Comment: the check on `window` will not worker inside a WebWorker ... :) however, the check against `process` will work canonically in all environments afaiu

Comment: another idea, to avoid checking on `process` in the browser: the global var `self` is an alternative to using `window` (but is equivalent to it in main thread) and refers to the global worker scope otherwise.

Comment: example: `if (typeof self === 'undefined') { /* neither web window nor web worker */ }`

Comment: As of 2021, Firefox browser has an object on the root called `process`, so the second method doesn't work unless you also check for the `title` attribute like this;

`typeof process === 'object' && process.title === 'node'`

Comment: `process.title === 'node'` does not work when node.js is started with an absolute path or the binary is renamed.

Answer (score 25):

There is an npm package just for this and it can be used both on client-side and server-side.

[browser-or-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-or-node)

You can use it in your code like this

```
import { isBrowser, isNode } from 'browser-or-node';

if (isBrowser) {
  // do browser only stuff
}

if (isNode) {
  // do node.js only stuff
}
```

*Disclaimer: I am the author of this package :)*

Comment: the function in this package does the best job possible +1

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work for me. Running my app through node / npm still returned isNode = false :( unless I misunderstood?

Answer (score -1):

You check for the `exports` variable, like this:

```
if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
    // only CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports,
    // like Node.
    module.exports = { ... };
}
```

Comment: For this to work, you'll need to make sure you don't have `window.exports` set in the browser, or else this duck-typing will fail.