# How to run few test suit in browser and few in Nodejs environment Mocha?

Tags: mocha.js, karma-runner, sinon, istanbul, karma-mocha

I have scenario like this:

```
const isBrowser = new Function("try {return this===window;}catch(e){ return false;}");

if(isBrowser){
//Run browser specific code
}else {
 // run nodejs specific code
}
```

I am setting up a test environment using Mocha, Chai and istanbul. How can i setup in such a way that few test suits should run on browser and few on NodeJs.

**The goal is to get the combined coverage report.**

how can I configure the Mocha to run in both browser and in NodeJs environment, using karma or without karma ?

for example:

```
//this should run in NodeJS Environment
describe('Loader Node Js', () => {
    it('Load files from File system', (done) => {
        loader.load('file path')
            .then((files) => {
                done();
            });
    });
});

//this should run in Browser Environment
describe('Loader Browser', () => {   
    it('Load files from Server AJAX', (done) => {
        loader.load('file url')
            .then((files) => {

                done();
            });
    });

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to test for Node.js and browser specific globals in your suite.

```js
if (typeof module === 'object') {

    //this should run in NodeJS Environment
    describe('Loader Node Js', () => {
        it('Load files from File system', (done) => {
            loader.load('file path')
                .then((files) => {
                    done();
                });
        });
    });

} else {

    //this should run in Browser Environment
    describe('Loader Browser', () => {   
        it('Load files from Server AJAX', (done) => {
            loader.load('file url')
                .then((files) => {
                    done();
                });
        });
    })
}
```

You have other options, too, like testing for `typeof self === 'undefined'`, which is `true` in Node.js and `false` in a browser.

There are a few related question you may find interesting:

- [Environment detection: node.js or browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575790/environment-detection-node-js-or-browser)
- [How to check whether a script is running under node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224606/how-to-check-whether-a-script-is-running-under-node-js)
- [How to detect if script is running in browser or in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550890/how-to-detect-if-script-is-running-in-browser-or-in-node-js/34550964)

Comment: But how will I get the combined coverage report. Using Mocha

Comment: Can you create separate coverage reports for Node.js and the browser with your Karma configuration? If so you can join them programmatically.

Comment: Did you mean `typeof this === 'undefined'`?

Comment: @thefourtheye Of course not. That could be true or false both in Node.js and in the browser depending on the execution context.

Comment: Okay, I don't know Karma. What does `self` mean here?

Comment: @thefourtheye It's a browser global, nothing related to Karma. Like `window`, but it's defined also in web workers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self

Comment: @GOTO0 Oh, I didn't know that. Thank you.