# How do I detect if I am running a .js file as a Node.js script or as a JScript script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jscript

Basically, there are two things that could happen if you run a .js file.
It can either be run with Windows Script Host, or with Node.js.

In the .js file itself, I need to know what is being used to run the script, and then run different code depending on that.

How do I do that, if that is even possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550890/how-to-detect-if-script-is-running-in-browser-or-in-node-js/48536927

Comment: @RaniSharim first I was gonna say "jscript aint browser tho" but the answer in that question makes sense so thank you

Answer (score 0):

`require.main === module` returns true if the script is executed directly with node. Otherwise, it returns false.