# Sharing config between node app and client side javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to have some config object both in the node app and in the browser. Here is the path and the content of the config:

path: [app]/public/js/config.js
content:

```
var config = {
    "foo": "bar",
    "num": 42,
    "list": ["a","b","f"]
};
var isBrowser=new Function("try {return this===window;}catch(e){ return false;}");
if(!isBrowser) {
    module.exports = config;
}
```

In my html I just add a script element and it works fine:

```
<script src="/js/config.js"></script>
```

In node app however I do not seem to have imported the object and I get an empty object:

```
var config = require('./public/js/config.js');
console.log('config:', config); // gives config: {}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need `module.exports = ` in the config.js for `require`  to work?

Comment: Why not using a standard [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) instead of the above function trick?

Comment: @AnthonyKong, I do have `module.exports =` in the config.js.

Comment: @ghybs, I'll test that to see if it takes care of the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `isBrowser` variable is assigned a function, but it is never executed.

Therefore it does not perform any environment detection.

Comment: Thanks! That part was borrowed (read copied) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31090240/66580) but I missed the function call part. Changing `if(!isBrowser) {` to `if(!isBrowser()) {` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The code should have been

```
if(!isBrowser()) {
    module.exports = config;
}
```

`isBrowser` is a function here. Since in your version `!isBrowser` always return `false` so `module.exports = config` is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

Replace if block

```
if(!isBrowser) {
    module.exports = config;
}
```

to

```
if(!isBrowser()) {//this isBrowser() function
    module.exports = config;
}
```