# In Vue.js how can I detect if code in created() hook runs in the browser?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue SSR-application and for some components, I need to know whether they run on Node during server-side rendering or whether they run on the browser.

I've set the process env in the Webpack config like

```
process.env.VUE_ENV === 'server'
```

which works. But for various reasons, I need a detection independent of the built environment.

I'd like to check for the browser/node in the created() hook.

How would I do that?

Comment: You can try to access a browser specific object (like navigator object) within your `created()` hook - and catch the error it throws when trying to access this object on nodejs fails

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224606/how-to-check-whether-a-script-is-running-under-node-js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took the following line -verbatim-  from the Vue.js source code ..

`const inBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';`

You can use it to verify if your code is running in the browser.