# Require a package on server only

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I require the package 'fs' on the server only and on the client resolve null?

If you try to run this on the client:
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'`

(The potential duplicate question [How to check whether a script is running under node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224606/how-to-check-whether-a-script-is-running-under-node-js) does not answer this problem)

```
const isNode =
  typeof process !== 'undefined' &&
  process.versions != null &&
  process.versions.node != null;

const fs = isNode && require('fs');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a script is running under node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224606/how-to-check-whether-a-script-is-running-under-node-js)

Comment: Last line should be `const fs = isNode ? require('fs') : null`

Comment: Another way to check for node environment `typeof process !== "undefined" && process.release && process.release.name === "node";`

Comment: We are already checking the node env. That is not the problem here.  require('fs') on the client will still fail.

Comment: Okay. Why not require condtionally inside if clause keeping fs as `let`. Unless you strictly want to keep it as `const`.

Comment: @AmbianBeing That doesn't work.  Even inside an 'if' require() will still be called.