# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "prompt-sync". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript

I got some related questions in stack overflow, but I am field to understand the answers. someone, please explain to me what to do.

Here is my JS code

```
    import p from "prompt-sync";
const prompt = p();

//for loop
let sum = 0;
let a = prompt("Enter number :");

for(let i=0;i<=a;i++)
{
    sum+=i;
}
console.log(sum);
```

I called this JS on the HTML page

```
<script type="module" src="JS/Loop.js"></script>
```

I am getting this error, in some solutions it mentioned like use URL but which Prompt URL should I have to import instead of prompt-sync

Comment: hey you can't use  that in browsers, it works only in nodejs like runtime. if you want to prompt use [window.prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)

Comment: @bogdanoff I have some code that is going to execute on the browser and some code on the console in the same JS page, so I have the import statement here is there any solution other than separating both browser and console code?

Comment: @DrTex — If you have a program running in Node.js and another program running in browsers then they are, by definition, different programs and need to be separated. (Any shared logic can go in modules that are part of both programs).

Comment: @DrTex you can differentiate by using one of  [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224606/how-to-check-whether-a-script-is-running-under-node-js) or using [this](https://github.com/flexdinesh/browser-or-node) package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give a module name to Node.js then it will search `node_modules` to find it.

Browsers can't do that. You need to give them a URL (which will typically end in `.js`).

If you want a relative path, then you need to explicitly start that path with `./` (or `../`). You can't just mention the name .

e.g.

```
import p from "../scripts/prompt-sync.js"
```

---

That said, [the module you are trying to use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt-sync) describes itself as:

> A sync prompt for node. very simple. no C++ bindings and no bash scripts.
>
> Works on Linux, OS X and Windows.

It makes use of Node.js specific APIs (e.g. [`var fs = require('fs');`](https://github.com/heapwolf/prompt-sync/blob/master/index.js#L3) and [`process.stdin`](https://github.com/heapwolf/prompt-sync/blob/master/index.js#L69)).

It isn't going to run in a browser environment.